# Doctrine2 one-to-many relation overwrite whole collection

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

Suppose I have two entities Page and Block. It's bi-directional mapping. Each page can have more than one block. Each block could belong to single page.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="page")
 */
class Page
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Block", mappedBy="page", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
    **/
    private $blocks;
    ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="block")
 */
class Block
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="blocks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     **/
    private $page;
    ...
}
```

From time to time blocks that belong to page will change. Some blocks will be added, some of them will be removed. The next case doesn't work for me:

```
$page->setBlocks([1, 2, 3]);
$em->merge($page)
$em->flush() //Page will have blocks 1, 2, 3

$page->setBlocks([1, 4])
$em->merge($page)
$em->flush() //Page will have blocks 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Expected result after second flush() call is: //Page will have 1, 4

So I need to overwrite completely collection of blocks with merge method.

Constraints:

- I can't implement deleteBlock in Page class
- I can only call merge() and flush() on $em

Is it possible to implement desired result via annotations or some other trick?

Comment: Your constraints are really weird

Comment: Yes, I know. But still I need a solution which won't manually iterate over 2 collections finding intersection

Comment: Note you needn't to do a merge because your $page entity is never detached in the code you give to us.

Comment: I didn't mentioned that, but the $page entity is deserialized from client request, so it's detached.

Answer (score 0):

### Addressing the Constraints

It cannot be done with your constraints.

---

### Suggested Solution

I'd create a custom function in the BlockRepository Class that deletes all blocks of the given Page, then call that function before calling the setBlock function.

Add this to your Block Repository class:

```
public function deleteBlocksByPageId($page_id)
{
  $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->delete('Block', 'b');
    ->where('b.page', ':page'));
    ->setParameter(':page', $page_id);

  $numDeleted = $qb->execute();

  return $numDeleted;
}
```

In your Controller:

```
//Delete all the existing blocks before adding them back in.
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BundleName:BlockRepository');
$repo->deleteBlocksByPageId($page->getId());

$page->setBlocks([1, 4])
$em->merge($page)
$em->flush()
```

---

### Conclusion

This is a common pattern for managing items that change often. It required no loops.

If the constraints are self-imposed then you need to loosen them and find another solution, such as the one I offer above. If they are constraints imposed by some higher-up then it's time to have a conversation with him/her about it being counter productive in this instance.